# My login or signUp doesn't directly navigate me to Home

Tags: flutter, firebase, performance, dart

When I try to log in or sign up using the provided forms, I expect to be redirected to the Home view of my application upon successful authentication. However, currently, after entering valid credentials and submitting the form, I remain on the login or sign-up page without being directed to the Home view even if I receive my token and make the login sucefful on debug

I got this after makign the login

D/FirebaseAuth(16316): Notifying id token listeners about user ( mvq79gN8zIVSyDZlHYZnQzbg6yb2 ).
I/flutter (16316): Signed in: mvq79gN8zIVSyDZlHYZnQzbg6yb2

But after this they don't redirect me to home page

This is my Auth